# Passing parameter to a vaadin 7 web application

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I was working with vaadin6 so i used the following method to retrive the web application parameters:

```
public abstract class Application implements URIHandler,
        Terminal.ErrorListener, Serializable {

    /**
     * Searches for the property with the specified name in this application.
     * This method returns <code>null</code> if the property is not found.
     * 
     * See {@link #start(URL, Properties, ApplicationContext)} how properties
     * are defined.
     * 
     * @param name
     *            the name of the property.
     * @return the value in this property list with the specified key value.
     */
    public String getProperty(String name) {
        return properties.getProperty(name);
    }

    //...
}
```

After migrating to vaadin7 i want to use the same functionnality but i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are looking for

```
VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext().getInitParameter("name");
```

It grants access to paramter defined in web.xml, for example:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>name</param-name>
  <param-value>John</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: In my case I got it working with: VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getInitParameter("name");